# How do I find the time complexity (Big O) of this block of code?

Tags: c++, c, big-o

I am trying to understand how this O notation works and I have below here a block of code, and next to each LINE I will have a comment with the time complexity that I believe it to be. If I am wrong please correct me and explain why my logic is not correct.

Code #1

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< O(1)*O(N)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< O(1)*O(1)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)*O(1)
          {
            printf("%d", arr[i]); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
           }
        printf("\n"); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
    }

}
```

Running time = O(N), after adding everything up.

Code #2

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) <<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)*O(N)
{
        int j;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
        printf("\n%d:", i);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
        for(j = 2; j <= i; j = j * 2) <<<<<<<<<<<O(n-2)??????????
        {
            printf("%d ", j);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
        }
         printf("\n%d:", i);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<O(1)
         for(int k = j/2; k >= 2; k = k / 2)<<<<<<<<<<<<<I am not sure of this one
        {
             printf("%d ", k);
        }
  }
```

Running time: Unsure..

Overall, I KINDA get the idea of it, but still not fully sure of how to use it in some situations. Does anyone else also have a guide or some sort that gives examples and explanations of the time complexity of for loops and while loops?

Comment: Hint for time complexity of the `k = k / 2` loop: How many times can you divide `(2^x)` by `2`, until you get to `2`?

Comment: @user3718584: Corect. `x`. Now how do you get from `n=2^x` to `x`?

Comment: Before we continue, where did he get the idea of 2^x / 2? Confused about his hint.

Comment: What's wrong with using comments in your code instead of `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`

Comment: @user3718584 Past experience.  And, if you're ending at `2`, after having divided by `2`, you must logically start somewhere around `2^x`... or something approximate along those lines.  And approximates are almost all we really need with time complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the block of k is `O(lg j)`, where j is `O(n)`, so k is `O(lg n)`. but if you considering to whole program, it's `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: actually O(n-2)=O(n).

Comment: Right, because we get rid of constants? How come on some other examples they just leave the constant there?

Comment: The j-block is O(log n) as well.

Comment: as long as you wish. it won't make you wrong if you insist. but it is somehow trivial to write.(under the context of O-notation)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh yeah, i see. i didn't pay attention to the increment.

Comment: The increment is times 2, why is the notation dividing?

Comment: j block is indeed `O(lg n)` since you twice j every iteration.

Comment: Do not the k block executes as many times as the block j (minus 1)?

Comment: Kinda confused. about why it's log n. Since log n is base 2, so it's 2^x = N. It's not multiplying by 2?

Comment: oh gee...i was wrong. such a pain in the ass. i confused myself too.

Comment: So, what do we do with the increment of *2?

Comment: it shrinks the complexity logarithmically with base of 2. by multiplying 2 in each iteration, j climbs exponentially. therefore its complexity goes down to log instead of linear.

Comment: I don't really get why it's O log n when you multiply by 2

Comment: if it's +1, every time it iterates through all n options. but if you multiply 2, say you have 16 options, so you start with 2, then 4,8,16. you only need 4 iterations instead of 16. it's proportional to `lg 16`=4.

Comment: Suppose the following setup: `for(int x = 1; x < n; x = x * 2) { ... }`.  If `n=16` then the loop runs for `x: 1, 2, 4, 8`, four times.  `log2(16) = 4`.  When `n=32` it runs `log2(32) = 5` times.  When `n=??` it runs `log2(n)` times.

Comment: the same case. having a simulation yourself will easily answer the question yourself.

Comment: @user3718584 its the same situation; however, the start and end positions are just reversed

Comment: Then the total running time is OlogN, since first loop is O(N) and the j and k times are just OlogN and since they are same we just add a single OlogN to O(N). Using the addition law, we take the faster one.

Comment: each iteration of outer loop takes `O(lg n)` and there are n of them. so it should be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the rules:

- Loop is number of iterations times complexity of the body
- Consecutive blocks are sum of complexities

  - But in O() only the asymptotically largest term is relevant, so you can immediately simplify to the higher complexity
- Multiplicative constants are irrelevant
- Geometric progression (the `j` loop with `j = j * 2` and the `k` loop with `k = k / 2`) has complexity `O(log n)`

Comment: what would be overall run time?